# Pandas Pivot Table: Values are shown twice in each cell

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I cannot understand why I have values in pandas dataframe shown twice in each cell.

Initially I download data from MySQL to pandas dataframe and format numbers as percentage points in column "monthly_perf":

```
    data_frame = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine)
    data_frame['monthly_perf']=data_frame['monthly_perf'].astype(float).map('{:,.2%}'.format)
```

The result looks good to me (partial data below):

```
start_date end_date   name  monthly_perf
1998-12-31 1999-01-31 TB3MS 0.36%
1999-01-31 1999-02-28 TB3MS 0.38%
1999-02-28 1999-03-31 TB3MS 0.37%
1999-03-31 1999-04-30 TB3MS 0.37%
1999-04-30 1999-05-31 TB3MS 0.38%
1999-05-31 1999-06-30 TB3MS 0.39%
```

Later I use data_frame to create a pivot table:

```
pivot_table = data_frame.pivot_table(values='monthly_perf', index=['end_date',], columns=['name'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

the result is weird:

```
start_date end_date   TB3MS
1998-12-31 1999-01-31 0.36%0.36%
1999-01-31 1999-02-28 0.38%0.38%
1999-02-28 1999-03-31 0.37%0.37%
1999-03-31 1999-04-30 0.37%0.37%
1999-04-30 1999-05-31 0.38%0.38%
1999-05-31 1999-06-30 0.39%0.39%
```

Every number is shown twice for some reason. Why? When I format pandas dataframe as %, do I turn everything into string format?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is if convert numbers to strings by `.map('{:,.2%}'.format` and then use `sum` it join them together.

You can try:

```
print ('0.36%' + '0.36%')
0.36%0.36%
```

So first processing by `pivot_table` numeric data and in last step add `%` with converting to strings.

EDIT:

```
data_frame = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine)

name_list = data_frame['name'].unique()
pivot_table = (data_frame.pivot_table(values='monthly_perf',
                                      index='end_date', 
                                      columns='name', 
                                      aggfunc=np.sum,
                                      fill_value=0).reset_index())
data_frame[fund_list]=data_frame[fund_list].astype('float').applymap('{:,.2%}'.format)
```

But it should working same like:

```
data_frame = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine)

pivot_table = (data_frame.pivot_table(values='monthly_perf',
                                      index='end_date', 
                                      columns='name', 
                                      aggfunc=np.sum,
                                      fill_value=0).reset_index())
data_frame = data_frame.astype('float').applymap('{:,.2%}'.format)
```

Comment: That is the major pain for me (I am still new to Pandas). The unique list of values (in column "name") is variable. When I use pivot, I do not understand how to format a list of pivot columns all at ones.

Comment: FInally, I came up with a solution: 
name_list = data_frame['name'].unique().tolist()

Comment: and then do the following: data_frame[fund_list]=data_frame[fund_list].astype('float').applymap('{:,.2%}'.format)